# Direction of gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do we know that gradient always points in direction of greatest increase of function and not the greatest decrease?

Comment: Can you please give an example to validate this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directional derivative along a normal vector $\vec{n}$ is

$$n_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+n_y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+n_z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=(\vec{n}\cdot \nabla)f=\vec{n}\cdot(\nabla f)$$

Directional derivative along itself ($\vec{n}=\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$):
$$\frac{1}{|\nabla f|}(\nabla f)\cdot(\nabla f)=|\nabla f|>0$$

while in the opposite direction, you get $-|\nabla f|$.

Comment: Can you please give an example to validate this

Comment: $f=x^2+y^2+z^2$. This is obviously increasing in the direction away from the center. Gradient: $\nabla f=(2x,2y,2z)$. Which of course is a vector that points away from the center. I used the directional derivative to demonstrate, because once you pick a direction, the derivative always just tells you the rate of change. I just upgraded this statement to the full gradient vector.

Comment: (Doubt)But also how is gradient at point is normal normal to it?

Answer (score 1):

If $h = \nabla f(x) \neq 0$, then $df(x,h) \lim_{t \downarrow 0} {f(x+th)-f(x) \over h }= \langle h,h \rangle = \|h\|^2 > 0$. Hence for some $\delta>0$, if $t \in (0,\delta)$ then $f(x+th) > f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you take the partial derivatives, if a function in the direction of an axis is increasing, the corresponding value in the gradient is positive, while when it's decreasing, it's negative.

So, if it is increasing in that direction, the arrow points towards it. If it is decreasing in that direction, the arrow points away from it. This makes sure that the gradient always points in the direction of increase.

Answer (score 0):

Each component of the gradient tells you how fast your function is changing with respect to the standard basis. It's not too far-fetched then to wonder, how fast the function might be changing with respect to some arbitrary direction? Letting v⃗  denote a unit vector, we can project along this direction in the natural way, namely via the dot product grad(f(a))⋅v⃗ . This is a fairly common definition of the directional derivative.

We can then ask in what direction is this quantity maximal? You'll recall that
grad(f(a))⋅v⃗ =|grad(f(a))||v⃗ |cos(θ)
Since v⃗  is unit, we have |grad(f)|cos(θ), which is maximal when cos(θ)=1, in particular when v⃗  points in the same direction as grad(f(a)).